# Skew matrices generate everything?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

(This is a reformulation of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221302/skew-elements-generate-everything) with a little less notation and theory.)

> Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero. Consider the matrix algebra $A = M_n(K)$, and let
>   $$
> S = \{X\in A\mid X^T = -X\}
> $$
>   be the set of skew matrices in $A$. Does $S$ generates $A$ as an algebra with unit?

It is obviously false if $n = 2$, but does it become true for $n\ge 3$ or for even larger $n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the canonical basis of $K^{n}$ (they are column vectors). Notice that $\{e_{i}e_j^t-e_je_i^t,\ 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ generates the subspace of skew symmetric matrices.

Now $(e_{i}e_j^t-e_je_i^t)(e_{j}e_i^t-e_ie_j^t)=e_{i}e_i^t+e_je_j^t$ and the set $\{e_{i}e_i^t+e_je_j^t,\ 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ generates the subspace of diagonal  matrices when $n\geq 3$.

Finally $(e_{i}e_i^t-e_je_j^t)(e_{i}e_j^t-e_je_i^t)=e_{i}e_j^t+e_je_i^t$. Now the set $\{e_{i}e_j^t+e_je_i^t,\ 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ generates the subspace of symmetric matrices.

So the algebra generated by the skew-symmetric matrices is $M_n(K)$.

Comment: What if I replace transposition by the map $X\mapsto X^* = U^{-1} A^T U$, where $U$ is any invertible matrix? Does $S = \{X\in A\mid X^* = -X\}$ still generate $A$?

Comment: Hi @Gaussler. I don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: I guess then it is just transposition with respect to the basis consisting of the row vectors in $U$?